# Azure - automating events based on new blob storage file triggers

Tags: azure, automation

I'm looking into automating some stuff in Azure and wanted to ask for tips.
The invironment: a VM that creates some local db backups, then sends them via azcopy to Blob Storage.
The goal: each time the the backup is copied to Blob Storage I want to test its correctness, so:
- power on an already prepared another db VM 
- copy the backup file from Blob Storage
- import it to the db VM
- do some checks
- shut down the db VM
- restore it to its previous state
- send a report if checks failed
From my reasearch it seems that I could utilise either Event Hub or Data Factory, both together with Azure Functions.
Which way would you recommend and what steps should I take (ie. create Data Factory event, make it react on trigger, create a pipeline with additional steps)? I'm a bit overwhelmed with all the options there are out there. Anyway, many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look at a combination of Azure Logic apps and Azure Automation to do this work.

Logic apps are Microsoft's cloud workflow engine, which can be triggered by a number of things, including [files arriving at blob storage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage#add-blob-storage-trigger). Logic apps allow you to build a workflow of different tasks, which can follow a specific order, have branching, error checking etc.

Logic apps will do the orchestration of tasks, then we can use Azure Automation to run PowerShell that actually does the work, seeing as how most of your tasks are Azure tasks, so Azure PowerShell is good for this. Each step in your workflow that needs to run a script will call out to Azure Automation, do the work and return the result.

Data Factory isn't going to do what you want, that is more concerned with moving and processing data, rather than performing tasks against Azure. Functions could do some of this, but you're going to hit issues with time limits of functions (10 mins max). The combination of Logic apps and PowerShell works well and is something I use a lot.

You could also just use Automation and one big PS script, but using a logic app lets you build a workflow, it also provides a way to trigger based on blob storage which Automation cannot do alone.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive insight. Will look into that!